# Pandas groupby datetimes converts to int64 in apply

Tags: python, pandas

I'm doing a groupby operation on a date column and found that the result was unexpectedly converted to int64.

Sample data:

```
> from deteutil import parser
> import pandas as pd

> df = pd.DataFrame({'id': ['a', 'b', 'b'], 'date': [parser.parse('2018-01-01'), parser.parse('2018-01-02'), parser.parse('2018-01-03')]})
> df

id  date
0   a   2018-01-01
1   b   2018-01-02
2   b   2018-01-03
```

This works as expected:

```
> df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: x.date.min())
id
a   2018-01-01
b   2018-01-02
dtype: datetime64[ns]
```

But do the same operation inside a series and the data type changes!

```
> df.groupby('id').apply(lambda x: pd.Series({'y':x.date.min()}))   
id  y
a   1514764800000000000
b   1514851200000000000
```

Any idea why?  Is this expected and can it be worked around?  Thanks.

Comment: I think it is bug . https://github.com/pandas-dev/pandas/pull/11672, same like agg , And why not just `df.groupby('id').date.min()`

Comment: I wanted to make a series with several columns so I need a series.  I agree it does look like the same bug, but it also looks like it should be fixed according to the commentary.  I have pandas v `0.23.4`.